# How do you Specify the default namespace for the file and Specify sites.xsd as the location of the schema for the default namespace?

Tags: xml, xsd

> So im trying to do this step for my code:
>
> In the sites.xml file, add a namespace declaration to the root sites element, associating
>   the xs prefix with the URI for the XML Schema namespace. Specify the default namespace
>   http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites for the file. Specify sites.xsd as the location of the
>   schema for the default namespace. But keep getting this error cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'sites'. im pretty sure my code is right but can you see if there is something wrong.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<sites xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xs:schemaLocation="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites sites.xsd"
xmlns ="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites">
    <site>
        <name>Weekend Fun Snacks</name>
        <totalPages>127</totalPages>
         <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=58</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=2</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-12-29T06:03:34+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=15</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-12-29T05:24:04+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=93</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=55</loc>
         </url>
      </urlset>
    </site>
    <site>
        <name>Paleo Snacks</name>
        <totalPages>52</totalPages>
              <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=6</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=18</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-09-19T17:13:19+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=54</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-09-19T15:24:01+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=52</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-09-28T21:03:11+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=201</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-10-06T07:03:26+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=11</loc>
         </url>
      </urlset>
    </site>
    <site>
        <name>Veg Snacks</name>
        <totalPages>17</totalPages>
              <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=102</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=23</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=1</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=55</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-06-12T08:05:32+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=201</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=87</loc>
         </url>
      </urlset>
    </site>
</sites>
```

> also in my xsd i only get this error "The prefix "cc" for attribute "cc:targetNamespace" associated with an element type "xs:schema" is not bound." but im also a little confused about a step and was wondering could you clarify what they are asking this the step:
>
> 5.In the sites.xsd file, in the root element, specify the target namespace as http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites, and then associate the prefix cc with the target namespace. Associate the prefix sm with the namespace http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9.Specify that elements are qualified by default, and that attributes are unqualified by default.
>   im not sure which prefix are they refering to and there isnt any attributes in the xsd to unqualify.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
cc:targetNamespace="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites"
sm:xmlns ="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

<xs:import namespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
 schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" />

   <xs:element name="sites">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="site" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                     <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="totalPages" ref="sitemap"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could make your sample work (Here it is assumed that `sites.xsd` is in the same directory.) by changing the top of you XML file to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
  <sites xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xs:schemaLocation="file://sites.xsd" xmlns ="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites">
```

Here, `xs:schemaLocation` specifies the path to the XSD and `xmlns:` sets the default namespace. In the XSD I removed the (wrong) namespaces `sm:` and `cc:` from the attributes of `xs:schema`.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites" xmlns ="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

See [here for an explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/schema_schema.asp) of these attributes. So, applied to your sample, the `targetNamespace="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites"` specifies that the elements defined by this schema come from the same namespace as the elements in your XML.

Applying these fixes, the XML validates.